# Dart SDK version error when getting dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I'm trying to add the `http` and image Dart packages. After adding the dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` and attempt to "Get dependencies", I'm getting the version error.

[image]

I have attempted "Check for Update" in `IntelliJ`, reinstall Flutter and Dart plug in in `IntelliJ`, redownload `Flutter`, and ran "flutter upgrade" in Flutter Console, with no luck. It seems the `Dart SDK` that comes with `Flutter` has not been updated.

I was able to download later version of `Dart SDK` independently, but if I just drop the `dart-sdk` folder of a newer version into the Flutter folder, I get more error still.

How can I update the `Dart SDK` in the `Flutter package`, so I can add dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason was flutter console being in the beta channel, causing flutter to not upgrade to latest version. Fix was `flutter channel dev` then `flutter upgrade` in console.